# set only 1 checkbox selected in java

Tags: java, checkbox, jframe

I'm trying to handle two events i.e. `openfile` and `newfile` with `checkbox` as setting only 1`checkbox` checked at a time.

**Minimal Code:**

**new File**

```
private void newfileActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    textArea.setText("");
    newfile.setSelected(true);
    setTitle(filename);
}
```

**openFile**

```
private void openfileActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    openfile.setSelected(true);

    FileDialog filedialog = new FileDialog(textEditorGui.this, "Open File", FileDialog.LOAD);
    filedialog.setVisible(true);

    if(filedialog.getFile() != null)
    {
        filename = filedialog.getDirectory() + filedialog.getFile();
        setTitle(filename);
    }
}
```

I've tried setting if else control as counter to check if the checkbox is selected, but It is not working. It's partially working, in this case the checkbox is getting checked but the `openfile` is not working.

I've tried setting if else control in both blocks to check if the checkbox is not selected then set that particular checkbox `true`.

Comment: Have a look at [`CheckBoxGroup`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CheckboxGroup.html) they are used exactly for this purpose. You don't need any extra code.

Comment: Add all checkboxes in the `CheckBoxGroup` which will allow to select only one checkbox at a time.

Comment: Have a look at [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) - search for "group"

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can use `JRadioButton` and `ButtonGroup` to select only one button at a time. Working code:

```
package com.stackoverflow.json;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class UI extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(500, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,2));

        JRadioButton rb1 = new JRadioButton("squirrel");
        rb1.addActionListener(e -> {
            System.out.println("man: " + ((JRadioButton) e.getSource()).isSelected());
        });
        JRadioButton rb2 = new JRadioButton("rabbit");
        rb2.addActionListener(e -> {
            System.out.println("weman: " + ((JRadioButton) e.getSource()).isSelected());
        });

        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        group.add(rb1);
        group.add(rb2);

        frame.getContentPane().add(rb1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.getContentPane().add(rb2, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```